# android honeycomb list menus

Tags: android

I feel stupid for asking: What are the drop menus on honeycomb apps called? I'd like to use them in my app but i don't even know where to start.

An Example from Google Music, notice the triangle in the corner:

[image: unopened menu]

Here it is opened:

[image: opened menu]

I found the Menu, which appears in the top right. I don't think they are context menus which you usually see associated with long holding touches.

(I realize these images are from the website, but they are all over honeycomb apps too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action bar will display your Activity's options menu in the top right automatically, but [`PopupMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) might be what you're looking for. It lets you generate a simple popup menu anchored to any View in your UI. Inflate a menu resource into the `Menu` object returned by `getMenu`, set a listener to respond to the user making a choice from the menu and call the `show` method.

Comment: I'm glad you could understand my incoherency.